# Using wpdb to connect to a different database is not working

Tags: php, database, mysql, wpdb

I am attempting to use wordpress built in database functionality to connect to a different database on local host. I am doing this in functions.php.

I have no problem achieving this with mysqli, the connection is made and I can test this by printing out the table names inside this database or any other query. However this is not the case with wpdb.

This is working :

`$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);`

This is not working:

```
$db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE, DB_SERVER);

$mytables=$db->get_results("SHOW TABLES");
foreach ($mytables as $mytable)
{
    foreach ($mytable as $t) 
    {       
        echo $t . "<br>";
    }
}
```

It does not show anything regardless of what query I use, I just get a blank page with a 200 response, indicating nothing is wrong but no data was found. Where as mysqli will show me the data without any problems.

I would just use mysqli but I want to use prepared statements, which does not seem to be an option on wordpress. I need to get that wpdb connectiong working if anyone could give me some clues as to why this does not work.

Comment: Where do you call it? Do you hook in the init action? Does this part where you echo your result return any output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had defined variables using the names DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD etc in my own database connection config file. I then found that wordpress already defines variables using these exact same names, which are stored in one of the files in the wp-includes directory. So my own defined variables with the same name were being overwritten or ignored when I attempted to use a wpdb connection.

The reason my own defined variables worked for my_sqli and not wpdb is, I assume, that calling a wpdb connection would fire up the script with these defined connection variables inside. I discovered this when using var_dump on the wpdb connection, where I discovered a completely random username was used instead of my own.

So if you want to use a wpdb connection and connect to a database with differing connection details, do not define variables named DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_SERVER and DB_DATABASE. Choose different names.